# Cordova project configuration: plugin VS gap:plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

What is the difference between these plugin declarations?

I can't figure out why I have them declared in different ways, however, everything works fine in my project.

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
```

Also, I'm not sure why I have to add plugins using this command:

```
cordova plugin add [PLUGIN_ID]
```

And then keep these references in config.xml.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: gap:plugin is for phonegap build plugins, if you use phonegap build you don't have to install the plugins from the CLI

Comment: I'm actually using Cordova. Do you mean that when I build, Cordova looks for all these plugins listed in config.xml and then installs them on the platform?? That is what I suspect.

Comment: That's strange, I've just tested an empty phonegap project and an empty cordova project and my cordova project don't have any gap:plugins, but the phonegap project has them. The gap:plugin are for getting the plugins installed when you use phonegap build. When using cordova <plugin name="[PLUGIN_ID]" version="X.Y.Z"/> will install the plugin automatically, you won't need to do cordova plugin add [PLUGIN_ID]

Answer (score 1):

## Specify plugins for local environment:

1. Install cordova plugin(s) with `cordova plugin add PLUGIN_NAME`.
2. Enter `cordova plugin save` in CMD.

When you open your config.xml you will see that your installed plugins are specified there.

For example when I install the plugin 'cordova-plugin-camera' and I enter `cordova plugin save` in the CMD then the result in the config.xml will be:

```xml
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~1.2.0" />
<!-- ~ = get cordova-plugin-camera version 1.2.0 or higher if available -->
```

## Specify plugins for PhoneGap Build:

1. Add the plugin specification manually in config.xml.

For example:

```xml
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="~1.2.0" />
```